# Rails: scaffolding command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would be appreciated if you could help me in this problem:

I am using rails 3.2.11 and I have already installed

```
"gem installed scaffold"
```

I do not know why it is not working for me

```
main$ rails generate scaffold idea name:string description:text picture:string
```

It give me this error:

```
Usage:  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

Comment: I might be wrong but my assumption is you are creating a project with scaffold from scratch in your main directory where there is no Gemfile is involved yet. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No I am not in app directory. Should I? My assumption is I use scaffold to create a project from scratch in my root directory where there is no Gemfile is there yet. Let me know please if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

`generate` command is for generating new code. `scaffold` is a type of generators, it is for generating models, controllers and views in existing application.

To create the project you have to use `rails new APP_PATH [options]`.

```
The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup cheat sheet:

In the terminal run the following command:

```
rails new "app name" --database=postgresql --skip-test-unit
```

In the gem file add the following:

```
    group :development, :test do
      gem "rspec-rails" 
      gem "factory_girl_rails" `<- only put in test group, not dev`
      gem "valid_attribute"
      gem "shoulda-matchers"
      gem "capybara"
      gem "launchy"
      gem "simple_form"
      gem "pry-rails"
       end
    group :production do
        gem 'rails_12factor'
    end
```

Run ' bundle install '  to install the gems

```
rails generate rspec:install
rails generate simple_form:install
```

in spec_helper file `require 'capybara/rails'`

valid_attribute also needs --> `require 'valid_attribute'` in the spec_helper.rb file

capybara will need -> `require 'spec_helper'` in each of the test files in the directory /spec/features/filename_spec.rb

You should see a number of files and directories created for you. The most important of these is the spec directory.

Now you can create models:  by tying the model generation process to the creation of the files and directories that RSpec wants, rspec-rails ensures that we have a testing environment that we need.

Add config/database.yml to /.gitignore file

Comment: @Keramat if the upvote doesn't work just click on the empty check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to get into your working folder before running the generate scaffold action. 
`cd "your_app"` then run `rails generate scaffold idea name:string description:text picture:string`